# stylesheet throwing a 404 error while loading into my WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am an absolute beginner to wordpress, I am taking a course on udemy to build a wordpress site from scratch using custome theme.
But my style's are not getting applied to my wordpress site and they are throwing 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(Not Found)'
I had a functions.php and enqueue.php files for loading styles
[[screenshots for my functions.php and enqueue.php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b88p.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNATs.png)

I tried to solve it,but couldn't

Comment: share your custom theme directory if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this: `get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/public/index.css' )`